# Technology for Server side DOM manipulation (Java vs Node)

Tags: node.js, dom, jsoup, server-side

I am doing a POC in which I have to manipulate DOM before giving HTML content to client/browser.

Some Use Cases:

1. Inject a javascript in html page and this javascript is customer
   specific.
2. Inject the stylesheet according to the theme chosen by user earlier.
3. ... More such cases are there with some business logic.

I have finished all use-cases. **I have implemented it in Java using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). I have also done it in [Node Js](http://nodejs.org). I have to decide which technology to choose ?**

Does anyone know any pros/cons in both techniques ?
Please suggest how should I test which of the two is better. Any tools available to test out the memory used/resource usage/time taken etc. 
Though I have already computed time in both cases.

PS: Please feel free to suggest any other technology for server side DOM manipulation and tools to test out its performance and memory.

Comment: Sounds like what you really want is a templating solution, so you can say {{ customerScript }} and {{ chosenStyle }} as placeholders in your  layout, and have the server slot in the appropriate code at request-time. Have a look at http://jlongster.github.io/nunjucks, which is great for Nodejs templating.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Apart from them, there are many other use cases (business logic) which needs DOM manipulation in various cases. So I can not use templating. Otherwise I could have chosen PHP as well.

Comment: DOM manipulation on server - can you mention what your goals are? Server side is too broad an area and you can do a lot of stuff. Is it just web-scraping, or modifying a local html ? Is it only browser imitation(headless), no clients to serve to or has clients which you will send the modified page? If clients are there will scraping be done for each one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Choosing between Java/Node.js depends on the application you are building and people will always come up with *benchmarks* to show performance on one is better than the other. Most of these suggestions will not suit your use case, so instead consider your application, TCO, time to develop etc as parameters apart from raw performance and take a call.

Remember that node.js is a single threaded async i/o model vs the multithread sync i/o model of java, and that node can be ridiculously fast out of the box whereas java comes with lot of features that can come in handy later. Again, these are subjective too.

I would suggest DOM manipulation is something you should avoid serverside and try to offload it to client side javascript or use better templating engines. If it is unavoidable, Node.js has good options - try to use the module [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) which is faster than heavy weight [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

Again, using these libraries has its tradeoffs. Cheerio does not have advanced DOM manipulations - it tries to achieve jquery like API on the server while jsdom is a full fledged DOM engine.

Comment: Thanks..I just wanted to know the tools to test out different technologies..I have found out now.

Comment: Glad to help. I have used cheerio, and would recommend it because of speed. So you decided to go with node then?

Answer (score -3):

It depends on your needs and setup. The question is what's the purpose:

- small app - use NodeJS, it will probably consume less memory than Java
- larger (modular app) - Java

You have to test them yourself. Regard the performance, resource usage and the speed of development.

We cannot choose for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..That's what I want to know how should I test for performance, resource usage etc..I have already calculated time taken in both cases..

Comment: Of course, one more thing is that Java is more mature than NodeJS but since ~half an year I don't hesitate to try^Wuse in my projects.

Comment: Nodejs is single threaded and Java is multithreaded..Can node js server handle multiple requests with ease!!

Comment: But NodeJS is event-driven while Java is not. One thread in Node is more powerful than dozens in Java. Some time ago we've been testing TCP server in node with my friend. Localhost, 100k connections, broadcasting 4-byte packet took... 7 seconds. One thread.

Comment: Your comparison between use cases of Java and Node.js has only a basic grounding in reality, and should be ignored.  As you said yourself, the choice depends on the situation, and I'm afraid your answer confuses that point even further.